# Wrap one line of text into a multiple line block

Tags: text-editing, keyboard-macros

I have a very long line of text (8000 characters). I would like to format this nicely so it splits across multiple lines in a block. Where the line breaks occurs does not matter for this purpose.

before:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
```

after:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
```

I chose eight characters before a line-break, but that number does not matter either- it could be 8 or 80. `fill-paragraph` does not seem to work for me- nothing happens.

N.B. I'm not asking about [Line Wrapping](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineWrap), or how the text is displayed.

Comment: @Drew I must disagree. This has nothing todo with keyboard macros. `(replace-regexp "\\(.\\{8\\}\\)" "\\1\n")` will also do. (Naturally I would use the equivalent interactive command.)

Comment: `fill-paragraph` does not work here because it breaks lines at whitespace.

Comment: @Tobias: The question does not ask about keyboard macros, true. But someone looking at questions tagged `keyboard-macros` might well be helped by this question. Feel free to remove the tag, if you feel that tag `text-editing` is enough or you have a more helpful tag in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a keyboard macro.  Generally using a keyboard macro means to record some steps for later reuse.  (Find documentation about keyboard macros within Emacs by entering `C-h F kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter <RET>`.)

Recent versions of Emacs provide the [function key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key) `<F3>` to start a recording of a keyboard macro and `<F4>` to finalize the recording and also replay the last recording (if not currently recording.)

To solve you question using a keyboard macro perform the following steps.

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of the line with the 8000 characters.
2. Press `<F3>` (to start macro recording.)
3. Perform the action. In this case e.g. move forward eight characters (press the left arrow key eight times) and press the enter key.
4. Press `<F4>` (to finalize the macro recording.  The macro then is recorded.)
5. Type `M-999 <F4>`. Concretely this (typically) means: hold down the Alt key, press the 9-key three times, release the Alt key, press `<F4>`.  **Explanation:** This plays the macro 999 times. Recall that `<F4>` replays the previously recorded macro.  One can further specify a number how often the macro will be replayed (see the Emacs documentation for "Arguments"). The `M-999` stands for 999 repetitions.
6. Be patient while the macro performs.
7. See the result of the transformation!

Comment: Please be more verbose. What does `F3` and `F4` do? Maybe somebody has re-mapped the keys. For an example consider users of ergomacs where `F3` is suggested for re-mapping by the user. What does `C-u 8` do?  What does `C-f` do?

Comment: What @Tobias said - that will help (e.g. show also the command name). But what is meant here are the *default* bindings of `F3` and `F4`. It's a judgment call whether someone should always spell out the default command bound to a key (e.g. `C-x C-f`).

Comment: @Marco Wahl, This did work. I must admit I didn't think of a macro, because I was hoping for a 'single command' to do what I wanted. Thanks for the help.